# Lebesgue Measurability and Weak CH

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, measure-theory, large-cardinals

Let $LM$ denote "all subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are Lebesgue measurable", and

$WCH$ (weak continuum hypothesis) denote "every uncountable subset of $\Bbb{R}$ can be be put into 1-1 correspondence with $\Bbb{R}$".

[**Warning:** in other contexts, weak CH means something totally different , i.e., it sometimes means $2^{\aleph_{0}} < 2^{\aleph_{1}}$].

We know that $LM$ and $WCH$ both hold in Solovay models. By forcing a (Ramsey) ultrafilter over a Solovay model one can also arrange $WCH+\neg LM$ (due to joint work of Di Prisco and Todorčević, who showed that the perfect set property holds in the generic extension).

This prompts my question ($DC$ below is dependent choice).

> **Question**: *Is it known, relative to appropriate large cardinal axioms, whether there is a model of $ZF+LM+DC+\neg WCH$?*

My question arose from an FOM-[question](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-August/015673.html) of Tim Chow, and my [answer](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-August/015674.html) to it; see also [Chow's response](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-August/015676.html).

Comment: What's your definition of uncountable: $\aleph_0 < |S|$ or $|S| \not\leq \aleph_0$ ?

Comment: I don't think there's a difference in this case - any non-finite set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is also Dedekind non-finite. This is because $S$ comes with a natural linear ordering, the restriction of the ordering on $\mathbb{R}$. Let $L_S=\lbrace x\in S:$ There are more than finitely many $y\in S$ with $y>x$ as real numbers$\rbrace$, and $R_S=\lbrace  x\in S:$ There are more than finitely many $y\in S$ with $y<x$ as real numbers$\rbrace$. Then either $L_S$ has no greatest member (in which case we can get an embedding of $\omega$ into $L_S$), or $R_S$ has no least member (cont'd.)

Comment: (in which case we can get an embedding of $\omega^*$ into $L_S$). Either way, we wind up with a subset of $S$ of cardinality $\aleph_0$. So if $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\vert S\vert\not\leq\aleph_0$, then $\aleph_0<\vert S\vert$.

Comment: Assuming $L_S$ has no greatest member, it does not follow that there is an embedding of $\omega$ into $L_S\hspace{.05 in}$.  See http://consequences.emich.edu/CONSEQ.HTM, form 13.

Comment: @Ricky and Noah: first of all, thanks for your comments. Next: I have added $DC$, since talk of $LM$ without it is rather silly (and of course with $DC$ the two notions of uncountability that Ricky asked about collapse to one).

Comment: How is $LM$ at all silly with just $CC$ instead of $DC\hspace{.01 in}$?$\hspace{.04 in}$ (That also make uncountability unambiguous.)

Comment: @Ricky: I know that CC is sufficient for the removal of ambiguity, but real analysis is so much smoother with $DC$, so I opted for it even though I realize it is not the most frugal option.

Comment: I've heard that Radon-Nikodym uses Dependent Choice; is that basically why?  I don't know of any other reason for real analysis to prefer DC over CC.

Comment: @Noah: What you are saying is not quite correct, we can have infinite Dedekind finite subsets of the reals. In fact, Arnie Miller proved recently that it is consistent to have a *Borel* such set. Of course, these worries go away under DC.

Comment: Arnie Miller proved that it is consistent to have a $F_{\sigma \delta}$ such set.

Comment: @Ricky: $DC$ comes handy in the proof of Baire Category Thm [indeed $DC$ is *equivalent* to Baire Category Thm for complete metric spaces (over $ZF$)]; and in Fubini's Thm (among other places). I found the following survey useful: www.drmaciver.com/docs/essay.pdf

Comment: Is that for complete defined in the 'right' way (with nets/filters), or with sequences?

Comment: @Ricky: sequences, as far as I remember.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the desired theory holds in the improved MAD family model from Section 5 of this paper : http://www.users.miamioh.edu/larsonpb/lru5.pdf

Comment: Horrowitz and Shelah have a paper which proves similar (better) results from a weaker large cardinal hypothesis. I'll have to ask them if they get the theory above. Both models add a generic MAD family to a Solovay model in such a way that all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable. The remaining question is whether you can embed the reals into the MAD family in these models, and in our case I'm pretty sure that you can't. I'll have to write up the details, of course. The Horrowitz-Shelah paper can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08327.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an expansion of my comments above. In the paper with Zapletal that I reference, we assume a proper class of Woodin cardinals and force over $L(\mathbb{R})$ with a partial order of countable approximations to a certain kind of MAD family (which Jindra named an "improved" MAD family). Although I have yet to write out the details, I believe that the resulting model satisfies LM (it clearly satisfies DC), and that, in this model, $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be injected into the generic MAD family. The arguments I have in mind are straightforward applications of the arguments given in the paper.

The paper of Horowitz and Shelah referenced in my second comment works from the assumption of a strongly inaccessible cardinal and, as I understand it, adds the construction of a generic MAD family to Solovay's argument. As shown in their paper, DC + LM hold in the resulting model. I wrote to Haim and asked if $\mathbb{R}$ can be injected into the generic MAD family in this model, and he said no. He says he'll update their paper to include a proof of this (so they'll probably have a proof out before we do).

Comment: When we were finishing our masters, Haim mocked me for doing choiceless stuff. Now look at him, the cat's pajama of the theory of the reals without choice. :D (And yes, I constantly bring this up when we talk.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer Paul; it is good to hear about the promising work of yours and others in relation to the question.

Comment: @AliEnayat The new edition of the Shelah and Horowitz paper [Madness and regularity properties](http://de.arxiv.org/pdf/1704.08327.pdf) addresses the question. See theorems 19 and 20 of their paper

Comment: @MohammadGolshani Thank you (I just now saw your comment).

Comment: I've posted a draft of a paper containing our proof. The relevant theorems are 4.3 and 4.9/4.11. See here: http://www.users.miamioh.edu/larsonpb/canonical_again.pdf

Comment: This might be a better link: [Addenda to "Canonical models for fragments of the Axiom of Choice"](https://web.archive.org/web/20230223142801/https://paulblarson.github.io/canonical_again.pdf).

Comment: Yes, my university stopped hosting our webpages. So it's now here : https://paulblarson.github.io/canonical_again.pdf