# A variant of Freiling's Axiom of Symmetry and a weak form of the Continuum Hypothesis in models where all sets of reals are Lebesgue measurable

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory, forcing, open-problems

Consider the following variant of [Freiling's Axiom of Symmetry, $\mathsf{AS}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freiling%27s_axiom_of_symmetry), which will be denoted $A_{< 2^{\aleph_0}}$:

- given any function $f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ into the families of of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ of size $< 2^{\aleph_0}$ there are $x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x_1 \notin f(x_2)$ and $x_2 \notin f(x_1)$.

Does $\mathsf{ZF} + A_{<2^{\aleph_0}} + \mathsf{LM}$ imply $\neg \mathsf{WCH}$?  If not, what is the current state of research in discovering models of $\mathsf{ZF}$ in which $\mathsf{LM} +\lnot \mathsf{WCH}$ holds?

Here

- $\mathsf{LM}$ is the statement that every set of reals is Lebesgue measurable,
- $\mathsf{WCH}$ is the statement that every uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ can be put into 1-1 correspondence with $\mathbb R$.

---

For background to this question, in his [3 August 2011 FOM post](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-August/015674.html) to Timothy Chow, Ali Enayat stated that

> $\mathsf{ZF} + \mathsf{AS} + \mathsf{LM} + \mathsf{WCH}$ holds in Solovay's
>   model since in Solovay's model every uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ has a
>   perfect subset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming $AD$, a version of the continuum hypothesis holds: every set of reals is either countable or of size continuum (this is a consequence of the *perfect set property*). So assuming $AD$, your $A_{<2^{\aleph_0}}$ and Freiling's $AS$ are equivalent. In particular, both can hold in Solovay's model, so the answer to your question is "no."

---

Your second question seems much more interesting. Off the top of my head, I don't see a reason why we can't have a model of ZF+DC+LM+$\neg$WCH (except of course for the small fact that I don't know how to build one).

Comment: Just to clarify what you wrote: Are you assuming that $\mathsf{AD}$ holds and $L(\mathbb{R})$ is a Solovay model? It seems that you are saying that $\mathsf{AD}$ alone implies that $L(\mathbb{R})$ is a Solovay model. (Well, you do not mention $L(\mathbb{R})$ but if this is not what you meant,  I am not sure I understand the "In particular".)

Comment: @Noahschweber:  Do you know of any research going on which might be useful in constructing a model of $ZF$+$DC$+$LM$+$\lnot$$WCH$?

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo quite right, that was a silly slip on my part; I've clarified.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Is this what you're looking for? https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72047/lebesgue-measurability-and-weak-ch?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Every model of **ZF** + **AS** + **LM** + **WCH** is a model of **ZF** + $A_{<2^{\aleph_0}}$ + **LM** + **WCH**, since **WCH** implies that any set of reals with cardinal $<2^{\aleph_0}$ is countable.